# Ionic 3 list of custom cards

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I created an ionic 3 application (for mobile devices) with several pages, using the ionic-tabs for navigation, and several custom cards created with ionic-card.

Also I added handlers from ionic life-cycle and Angular life-cycle on page ts and card ts.

I added a single card in one of the pages and I followed the traces: seems that the card is multiple times created and destroyed before the page show it.

Is this an ok behavior? I was expected that handlers from ionic and angular to be called once for the card as they are called once for the page.

I added the project [here](https://github.com/MihaiCatan/testionic.git).

I added traces and for Home page with one card I have 6 times the card view created and destroyed until it is displayed in the page.
There is no logic why for one card there are 6 cards created and destroyed.
Anyone any idea?

Update (ionic info):
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:
    Node : v9.5.0
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 10

Comment: Please add your code and describe better the environment (is it a web app or you build for devices etc), answering your question in vacuum would be pretty hard;/

Comment: Is the update better now?